# How to insert/update/delete form RDF Sesame using python rdflib?

Tags: python, rdf, rdflib

I'm kind of new in using sesame and I've build a python client application in order to query sesame opendrdf.

I've managed to retrieve data, but I can't do the write operations: `insert`, `update` and `delete`. I have a graph which has the name "graph" and a statement like

```
:BarackOabama :presidentOf :USA
```

and I want to insert something like this.

In order to do a python client applcation, I've used Cherrypy and Mako. This is how I retrived data. How can I change this code in order to insert or delete?

```
import cherrypy
import mako.template
import rdflib
server="http://localhost:8181/openrdf-sesame/"
command="repositories/456/statements"
myuri=rdflib.namespace.Namespace("http://ancaioana.com#")
class Site:
  @cherrypy.expose
  def index(self):
    tempgraph=rdflib.Graph()
    tempgraph.parse(server+command)
    myquery="select * where {:BarackObama a ?Z}"
    queryoutput=tempgraph.query(myquery)
    results=[x for x in queryoutput.result]
    results2=[(str(x[0])) for x in results]
    results3=[(x.rpartition("#")[2]) for x in results2 ]
 frontend=mako.template.Template(filename="query.txt")
 return frontend.render(names=results3,pref="http://ancaioana.com#")
cherrypy.quickstart(Site(),config="config.txt")
```

Comment: What this code does is simply download the entire contents of your remote Sesame database into a local Graph object, and then query that local object. I suspect that instead you should look at using rdflib as a client for a SPARQL endpoint (Sesame Server offers SPARQL endpoints on each database for both queries and updates).

Comment: Thank you. Can you give me any materials or tutorials to see how can I do this ? I have tried many options, but I can not figure out how it should be .

Comment: I'm no python expert, but I guess the [rdflib documentation](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) would be a good place to start.